# Restrict access to GCS Bucket to free access only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to make large scientific datasets freely available on Google Cloud Storage without incurring significant egress costs.

I know that I can enable "Requester Pays" fairly easily, however this stops anonymous access (which is surprisingly common in cloud-based scientific computation systems) or access by anyone who hasn't set up a billing account (which is most of my target users).

So two questions:

1. Is there a way to enable the Requester Pays in such a way that anonymous access is still accessible from within Google Cloud Platform (where presumably there would be no billing)?
2. Alternatively are there other mechanisms to restrict access of a dataset to only within Google Cloud Platform, so that I can keep the dataset freely available (without requester pays) but still be relatively confident that no one can download the dataset at cost to me and my group.

But really, the main question:

- What is the best way to host large datasets that provide both anonymous and free access to services running within the Google Cloud Platform?